# Why doesn't US English drop the "o" from "subpoena"?

Tags: orthography

US English usually drops the *o* from the diphthong *oe* (or *œ*).

So for example the *o* in the UK English *manoeuvre*, *diarrhoea*, *oesophagus* are all usually dropped in US English.

Why then isn't the *o* in *[subpoena](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subpoena)* also dropped in US English?

Perhaps this is just purely a historical accident. But is there perhaps any "logical" reason for this?

---

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subpoena%2Csubpena&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) suggests that there was a brief moment in the 1950s when *subpena* may have overtaken *subpoena*, but since then *subpena* has died out:

[image]

Comment: It's a term in law, and law terminology is very senescent.

Comment: Well, we drop the *o* when [we're speaking Spanish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_pena_de). :)